# SelectPDF Saving Difficulties

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, httpresponse, selectpdf

I have a project that requires me to create a PDF document based on the user inputs and decided to use `SelectPdf` as my tool. Any way, I created a dummy project to test the functionalities there and it works fine.

However, when I tried to integrate it to our existing project, it just doesn't seem to work.

The part where I'm having trouble is with this line of code:

```
doc.Save(Response, false "Sample.pdf")
```

I tried to put a break-point in it, but when I press continue, it does not hit other breakpoints on the code and nothing happens afterwards. Note that what I'm looking for is the prompt on my form to either open or save the document.

My best guess is it's with the `HttpResponse` `Page.Response` parameter, but I am not entirely sure what about it that causes the problem.

Please help me with this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Update: For the longest time I have finally figured out what I was missing. Apparently, I had to add the linkbutton/button to Postbacktrigger, since it the whole thing is inside an update panel and without it, it hinders the response to download anything from the browser.